# Can I pre-populate swagger body for a request via url?

Tags: workflow, swagger-2.0

For an api, I have a swagger in place. It shows a POST endpoint `/doFoo` that accepts json in the form of `{"baz": "poit"}`.

Swagger offers the possibility to enter POST parameter data and send them via a "Try it out!" functionality.

I now written a documentation in the form of:

1. Go to swagger
2. Select POST request `doFoo`
3. Enter parameter body value `{"baz": "realData"}`
4. Press "Try it out!"

I am wondering if I can streamline this process by providing a link that automatically goes to the request `getFoo` and fills in the body so that that one only has to press: "Try it out".

Is this possible? Or would I have to implement this myself?

Comment: Great minds think alike. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @BillButler Alas, I did not. The old process, albeit tedious, is working good enough.